# Host, get and display a huge library of various images

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-mvc-4, development-environment

We are developping an e-commerce application and I have a bit of a problem.

Right now we have 2 MVC applications:

1. A main MVC application which role is to manage the inventory and set items to sale;
2. Another MVC application which will serve as a the e-commerce on which the items set to sale by the main application will be displayed.

My main problem is that these two shares a same library of image, and this library is huge (about 60 000 images and counting). Up to now to allow a fast process each project has a physical copy of each images `"~/Images/BankImages/FullImage/theFirstImage.jpeg"`, and so on, but you can guess that this is a pretty huge library that takes a lot of room.

I'm looking for options on how I could develop something that would return an image in whichever C# format. I was thinking about a web service, I suppose, which task would be to return these images upon being called, but I don't know how I can do it (newb here) and I think I may lose a bit of speed because a call to the web service may not return immediately the needed image, and I may have to retrieve a few hundred of these images at the same time.

So I'm looking for suggestions. What would be the best way to solve my main problem and avoid (if possible) having to copy each time the whole image library?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: using a CDN probably can solve every problem

Comment: apart from using a CDN, i suggest you can reduce the resolution of image while showing this will significantly reduce the bandwidth usages.You can use amazon or something like that for CDN purposes.

Answer (score 0):

When You say:

> My main problem is that these two shares a same library of image

This mean you need a single assets repository, so you need a [CDN](https://developer.akamai.com/stuff/Caching/Large_Library.html), same asset, common API